# Domino Attachments Calculate total server space utilization

Tags: email, lotus-notes, attachment

We have been having trouble with users sending large attachments to many people. ex. 50mb attachment to 80 users causing 4GB of disk space to be used on domino server.  We do not have an attachment size limit, nor do we want to impose one, but is it possible to calculate the total size upon send? ex. 100 mb attachement to 2 users is ok, but 50 mb to 20 is not.

Answer (score 1):

I woiuld suggest that you use DAOS, then there will be only one copy of the attachment, and you don't have to worry about the attachment size.

Otherwise you can modify the mail template (which I recommend **not** doing unless you know what you are doing) and add some code there to count the number of recipients and check the file size of the attachment(s), and prevent the mail from being sent if above a certain size.
Look at the FileSize property of the NotesEmbeddedObject class to get the size of the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the message size configuring the server like this:

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_admin.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/64ebe467ebc25afa85256c1d00395871?OpenDocument

If you want something more flexible (*"100 mb attachement to 2 users is ok, but 50 mb to 20 is not."*) you will need to modify the template. As Karl-Henry says, it's not recommended if you don't know how to do it; but if this is your situation, you can you can look for a Lotus Notes developer. The modification is easy.